# Using the same commands for multiple files in R

Tags: r

Okay, so I have, like 45 files named, `D1 D2 .............. D 45` in my current working directory. Each file is of the form,

`Var 1   Var 2` with `1000's of rows in each file`.

What I wish to do, is execute some functions on each of these files, and then have them in my global environment by the same name, i.e. `D1` or `D2` for each file.

These operations are,

```
 colnames(file) <- c("a","b")
 file <- aggregate(count~a+b,transform(x,a=pmin(a,b), b=pmax(a,b), count=1),sum)
 file <- file[file$a != file$b,]
```

These operations I want to execute on each of the file in my current working directory and then get those files in my global environment.

I made a function, for this, and then used `apply` command, but it created this huge single matrix containing all the values. I want seperate files after the operations.

Comment: you could try it using `lapply`.  For example: `setNames(lapply(list.files(),function(x) {x1 <-read.table(x, header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=F); colnames(x1) <- c("a", "b")}), list.files())` and then do the rest of the operations.  Not tested without a reproducible example.

Comment: Try `lapply` indeed. The advantage is that you don't (!) end up with R objects for each file containing its output, but rather with one list containing them all. If the output is a vector or a single value for each file, `sapply` might be worth a look, too (same syntax). A `for` loop can also fill a pre-defined list in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do this in a loop. I can't test this since I don't have any sample data, but the general structure holds. I assume since you've got a table it can be read as a table into R, but you may need to replace this with a different function depending on how your data looks.

```
for(i in 1:45) {
  data <- read.table(paste0("inFileName", i, ".txt"), header = TRUE)
  colnames(data) <- c("a", "b")
  data <- aggregate(count~a+b,transform(x,a=pmin(a,b), b=pmax(a,b), count=1),sum)
  data <- data[data$a != data$b,]
  write.table(data, paste0("outFileName", i, ".txt"))
}
```